# Doctrine ArrayCollection with one-to-many throws an error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I get an error from Doctrine when persisting a one-to-many relationship. I've seen similar questions here, but the answers don't help, unfortunately.

Here is the error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 'Expected value of type &quot;Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array&quot; for association field &quot;Entities\Scripts#$ScriptsVersions&quot;, got &quot;Entities\ScriptsVersions&quot; instead.' in H:\SERVER\htdocs\10pages\www\php\Vendors\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException.php:206
```

Definition:

```
/**  
     *  @OneToMany(targetEntity="Scripts", mappedBy="ScriptsVersions",cascade={ "persist","remove"} ) 
    **/
    protected $ScriptsVersions;
```

Constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
$this->ScriptsVersions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }
```

Setter:

```
public function setScriptsVersions(ScriptsVersions $ScriptsVersions){
        if(!$this->ScriptsVersions->contains($ScriptsVersions)){
            $this->ScriptsVersions[] = $ScriptsVersions;
            $ScriptsVersions->setScripts($this);
        }
    }
```

If I dump the class of $this->ScriptsVersions after assigning it, it says  `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection`, but somehow UnityOfWork gets the object instead of the ArrayCollection...

Comment: The code you posted under "Definition" - is that on the `Scripts` entity?  If so, something is wrong - `targetEntity` should not be the same as the entity the association is defined on.  If you could post both sides of the association that would be helpful.

Comment: Oh! You are absolutely right. That's it, that's the error - just accidentally switched the targetEntity and mappedBy around and it didn't complain on the stage of creating the table from MetaData, but resulted in this error later. Do you want to submit the answer for me to mark correct?

Comment: Great, I have done, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment - the `targetEntity` in the code you pasted is not pointing at the correct entity class.  Glad I could help :)